# op-amp voltage follower - input volt is not equal to output volt

Tags: operational-amplifier

This is a fundamental question but I may be stuck in somewhere.
I have a circuit as below, the red texts are the actually values by a multimeter.
As you can see, for op-amp1 output, the simulator is the same as input, which is -1V, but actually, I have -3.2V.  The table in the right-lower corner is the current calculation, looks at all the voltages I am seeing is true.

Any inputs will be appreciated! Thank you so much!

Note, 
I've uploaded the physical circuit.
basically, we use this circuit to provide a pulse current at 10A with 30us pulse width.  The op-amp U1 is a current-to-voltage inverter, the U2 is the sense feedback. The BJT/FET is for high current capability.

However, not sure why, when the power supply and K57c/d is off.
I was seeing a noise(0-200mV at ~1k-10kHz) on U2 pin#3 (pos input). so I am checking this issue.

Thanks again!

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your power supply for OA1? Are you sure you just don't have the inputs for OA1 reversed?

Comment: Hi!  DKNguyen, it is dual-supply, +/-24V. the inputs are not reversed, but there are some protection diodes, which shouldn't be a problem....  I think.

Comment: I don't see a V1 anywhere in the circuit, and there are not voltage rails for your amplifiers, which is of vital importance to answering your question. And also, you should ask a question, this is a Q&A site

Comment: A photo of your physical circuit might help us see a problem.

Comment: @barryxian if there's protection diodes, why aren't these in your simulation?

Comment: Hi! The Photon, I've updated the physical circuit.     Thanks!
Hi! Marcus Müller, yes there are protection diodes, let me try and check on simulation. Thank you!

Comment: "*As you can see, for OPA1 output, the simulator is the same as input, which is -1V, but actually, I have -3.2V*", I can't understand this sentence. I can assume things and guess things which might be right, but I'm still guessing and assuming things, not understanding things.

Comment: What is "OPA" in your title? Op-amp? If so, I think it's not a standard abbreviation.

Comment: @Transistor Lots of TI opamps (500+) are called OPAxxxx. So, can imagine the use of OPA. Anyway, who defines the standard? :)